# Format JSON correctly

Tags: python, json

I have this JSON, which when fed into online JSON formatter websites, says JSON data not accurate.

```
  {
    "Hospitals":[
    {
    "name":"Centre"
    "url":"www.example.com"
    },
    {
    "name":"jdbcd"
    "url":"www.example.net"
    }
   ]
  }
```

I know the Correct JSON data is by putting comma at the end of name attribute

```
{
    "Hospitals":[
    {
    "name":"Centre",
    "url":"www.example.com"
    },
    {
    "name":"jdbcd",
    "url":"www.example.net"
    }
   ]
  }
```

But in actual I have a very huge data to format. How can i do this programmatically (because python's `json.load(file.json)` gives error) or any online resource(I checked top google results, none worked)

Comment: @downvoter: reason ?

Comment: Give us exact error that you are getting or link to file so we can try it...

Comment: Ohh, I thought, the error is visible.
Okay the error is missing comma at the end in name attribute

Comment: The first example is not valid json because the `,` characters are missing between name-value pairs in the objects.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo is right, you don't have comma at the end of first key-value pair in first example. If you have invalid JSON, json.load can not parse it right, so you have to fix it manualy.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo I also know this, and the same i have showed in the examples. and this is my question also

Comment: @Teemo: well that is exactly my question dude, how to correct that JSON data

Comment: why are you guys banging your head on correcting first JSON manually. I also know that and the same is written in question

Comment: Thank you for updating your question, your problem is clearer now. The stadlib json library only deals with syntactically correct json as far as I know. Either you fix it manually and parse it afterwards, or you write your own parser. Fixing it is probably easier if you never wrote parsers before.

Comment: Fix it manualy, mistake by mistake or write code that will do it for you.

Comment: @Prashant I think people (me included) didn't understand your problem until you updated the question.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo: Okay, can you tell me how to write parser for the same or any link to start with, because manually it's huge data

Comment: Why do you have that broken data in the first place? Fix it at the source?

Comment: Can't manipulate Source, it's a product which i am using. It gives output as mentioned

Comment: I don't understand, why i am getting negatives :(

Comment: Then I'd tell the creator of the product about the bug, so that they fix it.

Comment: I had already reported Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are supersets of json, such as [hjson](http://hjson.org/), that are less strict. I think hjson will work for you:

```
>>> import hjson
>>> hjson.loads("""  {
    "Hospitals":[
    {
    "name":"Centre"
    "url":"www.example.com"
    },
    {
    "name":"jdbcd"
    "url":"www.example.net"
    }
   ]
  }""")
OrderedDict([('Hospitals', [OrderedDict([('name', 'Centre'), ('url', 'www.example.com')]), OrderedDict([('name', 'jdbcd'), ('url', 'www.example.net')])])])
```